# Navigation Function in PHP using associative array

Tags: php

Create an empty variable named output. 
Write a foreach loop for the nav_sections variable. With each iteration, append to the output variable a listitem `(<li>)` with a hyperlink contained within. The array key should be displayed as the clickable text ofthe hyperlink. The href attribute should contain a concatenation of URL_ROOT (constant) and the array item’s value. Example: `<li><a href=”http://www.example.com/menu/”>Menu`
    Echo the output variable (this will echo the output in the place where the function is called).

This is what I have so far - Is this correct? Help me out here.

```
function main_nav()
{
$nav_sections= array(
     "Home" => "",
     "Menu" => "menu",
     "Members Club" => "vip",
     "About Us" => "about",
     "Contact Us" => "contact"
);

$output = "";

foreach($nav_sections AS $key => $value)
{
$output = '<li> <a href="' . URL_ROOT . $value '">' . $key '</a> </li>';
}

echo $output; 
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "Is this correct?"  Does your program output the expected value depending on the input?

Comment: This isn't really a question, but yeah, your code should be working as intended

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forget to concatenate output ?

```
foreach($nav_sections AS $key => $value)
{
    $output .= '<li> <a href="' . URL_ROOT . $value '">' . $key '</a> </li>';
}
```